# Creating files with correct index

Tags: output, tcl

I currently have a text file with 300 rows and 3 columns.

I need to loop over all the rows, assigning 3 variables with the values in the 3 columns.

Each time it loops through the for-loop, I need to produce one output file with the index number in the output file's name. (That is, in total, I need to produce 300 output files)

For example, for the 49th iteration, I need to produce an output file with the name **product-49.out**. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Sounds trivial provided you remember to `close` the file before the loop ends. You probably ought to learn how to write a procedure to write some data to a file; that'll make everything much easier for you…

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
set counter 1
set fp_in [open my-text-file.txt r]
set line [gets $fp_in]
while { ![eof $fp_in] } {
  # store the columns on the current line in variables:
  lassign $line var1 var2 var3
  set fp_out [open "product-$counter.out" w]
  # write one line from the input file to each output file:
  puts $fp_out $line
  close $fp_out
  set line [gets $fp_in]
  incr counter
}
close $fp_in
```